# No datalist popup when readonly unset by event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html-datalist

My input text element is bound to a datalist element and is set to readonly. When clicking on the input element its readonly property gets unset. But the datalist popup does not show up when entering text.

But is does show up when you unfocus the input element and refocus it.

```js
window.onload = init;
  
function init() {
  var e = document.getElementById('myText');
  e.addEventListener('click', function() { this.readOnly = false; });   
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type='text' id='myText' list='myList' readonly>
    <datalist id='myList'>
      <option>
        Test1
      </option>
    </datalist>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using Firefox 66.0.1.

/edit: Probably is this a security behaviour of Firefox with untrusted events? Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: Why did you make the input element readonly, and then used javascript to undo that? if you just remove the `readonly` attribute from the input element, everything works

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem and shortened the code instead of posting my complete project. It is part of a database table editor. Every input field is readonly unless you click on it to request write access (multi-user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the event from `click` to `mousedown`.

```
e.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { this.readOnly = false; });
```

My explanation to this is that the datalist element checks the readonly attribute of the input element when the focus event fires and decides after that if it should draw or not. The focus event occurs by the `mousedown` event. But the `click` event happens after the `mousedown` event. Therefore the readonly attribute got changed after the datalist checked the readonly attribute.